# No module named _curses

Tags: drivers, sudo, ncurses

I am very new to both Ubuntu and python. I am trying to run a code and getting : `ImportError: No module named _curses`.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install build-essential  
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

All reported they are already the newest version, nothing added, nothing upgraded.

*How should I proceed?*

*UPDATE*
The python version was 2.7.9, Ubuntu 14.04
After updating to 2.7.10 the error was gone.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy python` and `python --version`

Answer (score 0):

The `python` version was 2.7.9, Ubuntu 14.04. After updating to 2.7.10 the error was gone.